# Firebase functions multi child change

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

hi firebase functions I want to change multiple children, but cannot change all children under user id. can you help me with this topic

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var database = admin.database();

exports.newNodeDetected = functions.database.ref('system/{userId}/value')
.onWrite((Change) =>{
    var oldDeger = Change.before.val();
    var newDeger = Change.after.val();
    


    if (newDeger === '0'){  
     database.ref(`system/${userId}/value`).set('1');    
    }
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2v2y.png)

Comment: Why can't you change multiple children? What's keeping you from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update multiple children in several ways using standard object manipulation and direct writes as demonstrated in your question.
You may be interested in using `update` rather than `set` when updating multiple fields.

You will also notice I added a `Context` field which allows you to access information such as the userID from the reference path and other information: [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#index)

```js
exports.newNodeDetected = functions.database.ref('system/{userId}/value')
.onWrite((Change, Context) =>{
    var oldDeger = Change.before.val();
    var newDeger = Change.after.val();
    


    if (newDeger === '0'){  
     database.ref(`system/${Context.params.userId}/value`).set('1'); 
     database.ref(`system/${Context.params.userId}/otherField`).update({another:field});
    }
})
```

Resource: [Medium Article: Realtime Set Vs Update](https://medium.com/@jasonbyrne/closer-look-at-firebase-set-versus-update-eceff34d056b)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have one more question. how can I put this function in a timed trigger. node js i am learning new.                                                                                                            exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 3 minutes').onRun((context) => {

  
    return null;
});

Comment: You certainly can, you just need to ensure the logic can search and identify the documents as needed. both solutions are valid and have different impacts on billing should your app scale.